# MySQL / PHP search function?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm working with a group in my Comp. Sci class on this website project with PHP, mySQL and HTML, and we're having some trouble with a search function.

Here is the full code:

```
    <html>

<head>
  <title>US Cities Database</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script>

  function doWhenReady () {
    $('a').click(showMap);
  };

  function showMap(event) {
    var element = $(event.currentTarget);
    var lat = element.attr('lat');
    var long = element.attr('long');
    var url = "https://maps.google.com/maps?q="+lat+","+long+"&h1=es&z=12&t=m&output=embed";
    $('iframe').attr('src', url);
  }

  $(document).ready(doWhenReady);

</script>

<body class="container">

  <h4>US Cities Zip Code and Latitude / Longitude Locator</h4>
  <p><strong>Make sure to enter the smaller Zip Code in the first box, and the larger Zip Code in the second box.</strong></p>
  <form action="index.php" method="POST" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="city">City</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="state">State</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="state" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="zipFrom">Zipcode from:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zipFrom" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="zipTo">to:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zipTo" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">Search</button>

  </form>
  <hr>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 scrollable">
      <div class="search-results">
        <h4>Search results:</h4>

<?php

  $host = 'localhost';
  $username = 'caleyhalpern';
  $password = '';
  $dbName = 'project224';   

  $db = mysqli_connect ($host, $username, $password, $dbName);
  if (!$db) {
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error); 
  }

  $searchCity = $_POST['city'];
  $searchState = $_POST['state'];
  $searchZipCode = $_POST['zipcode'];
if ((isset($searchCity) || isset($searchState)) && (($searchCity != '') || ($searchState != ''))) 
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM zips WHERE city LIKE "%'.$searchCity.'%" AND state LIKE "%'.$searchState.'%"';
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $resultArray = mysqli_fetch_all($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>

        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed small">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Show</th>
              <th>Zip</th>
              <th>State</th>
              <th>City</th>
              <th>Lat</th>
              <th>Long</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
<?php
    foreach($resultArray as $city) {
      echo "<tr>";                      
      echo '<td><a href="#" lat="'.$city['lat'].'" long="'.$city['lng'].'">Show</a></td>';
      echo "<td>".$city['zip']."</td>";   
      echo "<td>".$city['state']."</td>"; 
      echo "<td>".$city['city']."</td>";  
      echo "<td>".$city['lat']."</td>";   
      echo "<td>".$city['lng']."</td>";   
      echo "</tr>";                    
    }
?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
<?php
  }  
?>        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <div class="map">
        <h4>Map:</h4>

        <iframe src=""></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Sorry it's kind of lengthy, but if you scroll down to the PHP section, you'll see the "if((isset(...", and that's where we are having trouble.  We have the search function for the cities and states, yet we're having trouble with the Zip Codes search function.  We're trying to make it so the user inputs two zip codes, the smaller zip code going in the first search box, and the larger zip code going in the second search box. (For ex: 1st: 82190, and 2nd: 92120).  And it will search for every zip code in between those two that the user put in.  I understand that the search function will be similar to that of the city's/state's- we're just new to PHP and MySQL and are struggling a bit.

Comment: What's the datatype of your `zipcode` column in the database?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query. Try to be careful with these things, it can be a serious problem if you forget. Using parameterized queries reduces the chances a simple mistake will cause your code to break.

Comment: You sure you don't want `... OR state LIKE...` instead of `AND` in your query?

Comment: Please be more specific than "We are having trouble". That tells us absolutely nothing about what type of outputs you are expecting, and what outputs you are getting instead.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax it say's the type is int(5)

Comment: @frosty Well, if you didn't see at the bottom, I explained what we're trying to accomplish - getting the program to search between two zip codes which the user will input.  We tried using the same sort of search function as the city/states, yet it would just list every single city, etc., in the database.  So we got rid of that, and now we're not sure what to do.

Comment: @Qirel  Our teacher gave us some base code to work off of, and that's what he had given us- so maybe he did it wrong, I'm not sure.

Comment: If I understood it correctly you want to get the range of zipcodes... you can use `>=` and `<=`.. don't use wildcard.

Comment: This is what I see: SELECT * FROM zips WHERE city LIKE "%'.$searchCity.'%" AND state LIKE "%'.$searchState.'% This has nothing of the between zip code so and so. So, why don't post the actual code that isn't working for you, and we'll try to fix it for you?

Comment: @SamTengWong Yes, that's what we are trying to do.  The user would input a smaller/lesser zip code (sorry, not sure how else to explain that) in the first Zip Code search box, and the larger one in the second Zip Code search box- and the program would list every zip code in between those two.

Comment: try this `SELECT * FROM zips WHERE zip_code >= $from AND zipcode <= $to`.... hope this helps you.. if you have time use parameterized query instead...

Comment: @frosty  I edited the "if(isset..." line with what we first tried.  It's just a guess, though. But I'm just really not sure what to do for the the SELECT part for the zip codes because there's two zip code search boxes (zipFrom and zipTo).  Sorry I'm not of much help with that.

Comment: You're not even getting the two correct zip codes. First of all, you're trying to get $_POST['zipcode']. There are no such inputs with the name of 'zipcode'. The first one is named, 'zipFrom' and the second one is named, 'zipTo'. So first, you need to get the 2 correct zip codes. Then use them in the query to get the zips in between the two zip codes.

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to check that the two zip code fields are numeric, and if not, then set a default value, say `00000` for `$zipFrom` and `99999` for `$zipTo`.

```
$zipFrom = $_POST['zipFrom'];
if (!is_numeric($zipFrom))
  $zipFrom = 0;
```

Handle the value of `$zipTo` similarly. You should also check that `$zipFrom <= $zipTo` and swap them if not. (Always, always, *always* program defensively!) After that, the query itself is simple. Here's how to do it with a prepared statement:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM zips
            WHERE zipcode >= ?
              AND zipCode <= ?';
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $zipFrom, $zipTo);
$stmt->execute();
$rslt = $stmt->get_result();
$resultArray = $rslt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

The call to `bind_param` maps the two variables to the two question-mark placeholders in the query. The first argument (`'ii'`) specifies the data types of the values.

I leave error handling as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score -2):

You could try something like this...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM zips WHERE city LIKE '%".$searchCity."%')";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        echo $row['zip'];
        // echo any others you need
    }
}
```